# Trying to print or access value inside a multidimensional VBA array

Tags: arrays, vba

'For the most part, I understand how arrays work but apparently not multidimensional ones in VBA. Below is a simple subroutine in which I want to debug.print/access the value E or S from the multi-dimensional array below. can someone explain? I suspect I am not declaring the array properly.

```
Sub car()

    ReDim carData(3, 21)

        carData(0, 0, 0, 0) = "ID" '
        carData(0, 1, 0, 0) = "UUID"
        carData(0, 2, 0, 0) = "Active" 
        carData(0, 3, 0, 0) = "Model Number" 
        carData(0, 4, 0, 0) = "bla bla" 
        carData(0, 5, 0, 0) = "bla bla"
       ' ... 
       ' pretend like I wrote this all the way out to 18...
       ' ...
        carData(0, 18, 0, 0) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 1) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 2) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 3) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 1, 0) = "E" '<----- I want to access this value.
        carData(0, 18, 1, 1) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 1, 2) = "S"
        carData(0, 18, 1, 3) = ""
        
        carData(0, 19, 0, 0) = ""
        carData(0, 20, 0, 0) = ""
    
        Debug.Print carData(0, 19, 1, 0)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are declaring `carData` with two dimensions, then you are accessing it once as if it had four, and then you are accessing `poleData` about which we don't know anything.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed the sub. Also, I figured out the issue, thanks for clearing up the declaration issue. I was able to quickly adjust the code to get the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not declare the correct dimension level and the array was named differently in certain places. Anyways I'll leave the answer below for anyone who might experience the same issue.

```
Sub car()

    ReDim carData(3, 22, 1, 3)

        carData(0, 0, 0, 0) = "ID" '
        carData(0, 1, 0, 0) = "UUID"
        carData(0, 2, 0, 0) = "Active" 
        carData(0, 3, 0, 0) = "Model Number" 
        carData(0, 4, 0, 0) = "bla bla" 
        carData(0, 5, 0, 0) = "bla bla"
       ' ... 
       ' pretend like I wrote this all the way out to 18...
       ' ...
        carData(0, 18, 0, 0) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 1) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 2) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 0, 3) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 1, 0) = "E" '<----- I want to access this value.
        carData(0, 18, 1, 1) = ""
        carData(0, 18, 1, 2) = "S"
        carData(0, 18, 1, 3) = ""
        
        carData(0, 19, 0, 0) = ""
        carData(0, 20, 0, 0) = ""
    
        Debug.Print carData(0, 18, 1, 0)
    
End Sub
```